# The thread 'Win32 Thread' has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, crash, c++-cli

I have an executable which calls a DLL. I can step through DLL code by attaching VS2008 project of DLL to process of executable. I debugged some errors/exceptions already. But now, exactly when main function of DLL returns, executable process crashes without any error/exception. To debug the crash, I tried to use crash-dump file, but based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4699467/3405291), looks like they don't work with VS2008.

What possible tools can I use to debug the crash?

### EDIT:

process calls this when dying:

```
TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER);
```

Comment: Are you using managed 9.Net) code or native? The C++ tags suggests native, but you link to a question about managed code.  Also, what exactly is a "crash"? That's not a technical term. If your process just calls `TerminateProcess` for whatever reason, it silently goes away but that's not a true crash.

Comment: Crash dumps can be used with VS 2008.   `when main function of DLL returns, executable process crashes without any error/exception`.  When debugging, the "Output Window" in Visual Studio lets you know what the return value and/or unhandled exception is.  VS doesn't leave you with no information.

Comment: @MSalters process calls this: `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER);` Does it mean process goes away or is it a true crash? I'm not sure.

Comment: @user3405291: That's the kind of details that you should have put in the question originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER);` is a strong indication that the runtime library terminated your process because you passed a bad parameter to a library function. And "bad" was so bad that it couldn't reasonably continue. You're probably not looking at something as trivial as `sqrt(-1.0)`, but perhaps `strlen(NULL)` or `std::sort(... , &std::equal<int>)`

[edit]
To find the root cause, it can help to provide a [`invalid_parameter_handler)(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb(v=vs.90).aspx). In it, call `__debugbreak` to invoke the debugger. The stack trace will now show the cause.

Comment: I wonder why my bad parameter is not causing any error/exception message.

Comment: Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger call-stack implies that a bad parameter is passed to `fscanf` and then consequently `vfscanf`. Considering crash happens exactly when DLL returns, I'm not sure if bad call to `fscanf` is inside DLL or executable. Is there any approach to realize that?

Comment: Well, that's potentially a good reason for a library to call `TerminateProcess`. You pass a pointer to ` fscanf` and say "put the result here". Passing a bad pointer could very well cause random data to be overwritten, with unpredictable consequences. This kind of problem has lead to security bugs in the past, which justifies a quick exit. A dead process no longer is a security risk.

Comment: I implemented `_set_invalid_parameter_handler` and `__debugbreak()` inside source code of DLL but it couldn't invoke debugger. I feel like bad parameter of `fscanf` happens in executable (which I don't have its source code). It makes sense to me because crash happens just after main function of DLL returns.