# Debug dump file for .NET 3.5 application

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, dump

I haven't debugged a dump file before. My application got stuck and was not working as expected, so I took a dump of it using Windows `Task Manager`.

The application is built using `.NET 3.5`. I am opening the dump file in Visual Studio 2013 and started debugging (`Debug with Native Only`). I specified file-system path of the dll, exe and pdf files in the Symbols. But still when the debugging starts it says it is not able to find main.exe and when I select to continue anyway, it takes me to Windows System modules like ntdll, KernelBase, sechost and shows their method call in call stack or Disassembly (as source not available).

I followed guidelines at:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d5zhxt22.aspx
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx

I want to check what were the values of some properties in a specific class-instance. Is there a way to do it ? Please guide...

Comment: analyze the dmp with Windbg + SOS extension.

Comment: Do you have a [dump of correct bitness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net)?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google(ing), gave me these resources

- [First look at debugging .NET 4.0 dumps in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/06/16/first-look-at-debugging-net-4-0-dumps-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
- [Post-Mortem Debugging Your Application with Minidumps and Visual Studio .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1934/Post-Mortem-Debugging-Your-Application-with-Minidu)
- [Debugging dump files in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699285/debugging-dump-files-in-visual-studio)

Comment: My applicaiton is in .NET 3.5 and two links you provided are for .NET 4.0 which supports `Debug with Mixed`. The remaining link is very old using Visual Studio .NET